# Como impedir o submit de um formulário vazio?

Tags: javascript

Tenho um formulario customizado de pesquisa para o Google Search, e quero que, se o campo de pesquisa estiver vazio, o submit não aconteça.

Tem como fazer esse bloqueio via JavaScript?

Answer (score 14):

Você pode fazer via JavaScript

```
$("#form").submit(function() {
    if($("#campo").val()== null || $("#campo").val() ==""){
        alert('campo vazio');      
        return false;
    }
});
```

ou você pode usar HTML5

```
<input name="campo" id="campo" required/>
```

Comment: Nota: Internet Explorer 9 ou mais antigo não compreende o `required`. No entanto evitar JS desnecessário é sempre bom.

Comment: Além disso, ainda não tem boa aceitação em móveis.

Answer (score 5):

Uma outra forma [que pessoalmente, eu acho bem simples e completa] via JS é em vez de usar um `submit`, usar um `button` com uma função `salvar()`.
Dentro na função criamos as regras de negocio e se todas condições forem verdadeiras, é só utilizar a linha de código

```
document.form.submit();
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o comando require HTML 5:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<form>
  <h1> Formulário Simples </h1>
  <div>
  <input type="text" id="txtNome" placeholder="Digite seu nome" required="required"/><span class="required">*</span>
    </div>
  <div>
  <input type="idade" id="txtIdade" placeholder="Digite sua idade" required="required"/><span class="required">*</span>
    </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
  <span>Enviar</span>
  </button>
</form>
  </div>
```

Comment: detalhe, vc coloco o  required="required" do primeiro campo no lugar errado velho :)

Comment: Verdade... Obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".form").submit(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();//evito o submit do form ao apetar o enter..
      });
 });
</script>
```

E ainda usaria a logica sugerida pelo PauloDias em uma função onde eu a chamaria nos eventos onclick e keyUp

Answer (score 1):

Use o atributo HTML5 `required` com *fallback* para os navegadores (ou versões) que não suportam esse atributo, que representam 30% dos usuários globais e 15% dos usuários no Brasil, atualmente (novembro de 2014), [segundo o site Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#search=required) - Uma fatia considerável.

Código a seguir:
<sub>(Favor, desconsiderar as más práticas de Experiência do Usuário (UX) e estrutura do HTML.)</sub>

```js
if ($("<input />").prop("required") === undefined) {
  $(document).on("submit", function(e) {
    $(this)
      .find("input, select, textarea")
      .filter("[required]")
      .filter(function() { return this.value == ''; })
      .each(function() {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).css({ "border": "2px solid red" })
        alert($(this).prev('label').html() + " é obrigatório.");
      });
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
    <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
    <input type="text" id="nome" required /><br>
    <label for="nome">E-mail:</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" required /><br>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro que adicione sempre o Script abaixo no script no projeto, para que todos os campos do tipo text que possui a tag required serão validados se possui o campo vazio e ou que possui somente espaços "  ".

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
 
/**REQUIRED**/
$("input[required]").each(function(index) {
/** Utiliza por padrão o placeholder caso não encontre, utiliza o texto do label **/
var field = $(this).attr("placeholder") != null ? $(this).attr("placeholder") : $(this).parent().find("label").text();
$(this).rules("add", {
 required : function(element) {
  if(!$(element).val().trim()) {
   $(element).val("");
   return true;
   }
  return false;
     },
 messages : {required : "Campo é de preenchimento obrigatório."}
 });
});

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```